# Is there a word for a fake radar reading?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a radar (or any other kind of detection device) reading that is known to be false?

Comment: A *red herring*, a *decoy*, etc?

Comment: "9/11 conspiracy theory"

Comment: I'm not sure what a *red herring* is, but a decoy is a function, I need a name for the object itself.

Comment: A *red herring* is "[Something that is not relevant that makes you confused or takes your attention away from what you should be concentrating on](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus/american/red-herring)".

Comment: A decoy is also an object (ask any duck hunter) but I agree it's not what you are looking for.

Comment: @itsbruce, a *decoy* set by the enemy as a *distraction* or *diversionary tactic* would show up on the radar as a *red herring* or *false signal* and send ilyo on a *wild goose chase*.

Comment: Do you mean accidental false readings, caused by technical failure or poor signal quality (interference, weather conditions etc)?  Or do you mean deliberate deception causing false readings (chaff and other technologies)?  Or both?

Comment: Either intentional or accidental false readings would be *red herrings*.

Comment: @DanBron red herring is not a very common term, so it's not what I'm looking for. I thought about `bogey` but I'm not sure if it's applicable for something that is not an airplane/spaceship...

Comment: @ilyo, a *bogey* is not a *false* reading, it's an *unidentified* reading (which, for the sake of being conservative, is *assumed* to be hostile).  And *red herring* is [a very common term](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=red+herring&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cred%20herring%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bred%20herring%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRed%20Herring%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRed%20herring%3B%2Cc0), though I agree not in this context.

Answer (score 17):

It's called a [***ghost image***](http://digital-library.theiet.org/content/journals/10.1049/iet-rsn.2012.0191). That link is to a scientific paper entitled:

> *Ghost image cancellation algorithm through numeric beamforming for multi-antenna radar imaging*

Comment: "Artifact" is often used to denote a sensor reading (both in radar and in other technologies) that is somehow not "real" but due to the sensor system or the environment.

Comment: *Artefact* is an unknown or otherwise yet-to-be identifiable entity until further confirmation.

Comment: Note that ghost images are secondary images of a true target. They're in the wrong place, but still indicate the presence of an object in the radar range (or at least near that). So this is probably too specific a term, as not all false readings are due to ghosting.

Comment: @MSalters: I did know that (or at least, I strongly suspected as much). But to me, ***artefact/artifact*** more often suggests errors caused by problems with software algorithms, and until now I didn't know about the domain-specific ***clutter***. At least ***ghost image*** is a usage I've come across reasonably often in this context, so it's probably what ***I*** would use myself.

Comment: Huh. I'm sure I've heard this called a "radar ghost", but google searching doesn't confirm.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - Google "radar artifact" and you will get a number of hits.

Comment: This is not quite a complete answer.  Ghost images are fake radar readings caused as a side effect of imperfect receiver equipment or processing.  There are other forms of fake radar readings which are not considered ghost images, such as "False Targets" which are generated by some classes of radar jammers.

Comment: @HotLicks: *Artifact* was the first word I thought of, as well.  Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 12):

***False reading*** is the most common phrase. It can be applied to different kind of radars and other kind of devices as well.

> If the antenna part of a radar unit is hung on the outside of the police officer's car , the beam can actually hit a side window or part of the window and a **false reading** occurs which will distort the actual reading for the targeted vehicle.
>
> [Radar Unit Accuracy](http://www.speedingtickethelp.info/information/9-radar-unit-accuracy.shtml)

---

> The RADAR system is a reliable way of measuring speed, but it is not perfect. Radar works by reflective capability. A tractor-trailer has five times the reflective capability as a standard motor vehicle. There are several factors that influence RADAR. If the operator is not familiar with these factors a **false reading** could be obtained.
>
> [Defending Your Ticket in Court](http://www.speedright.com/advice.html)

For specific type of radars like ARPA, there is the term ***false echo*** or ***spurious echo***. There are specific type of *false echoes* like *indirect echoes* also.

[image]

You can read further in this book: 
[Radar and ARPA Manual *By A. G. Bole, W. O. Dineley*](http://books.google.ca/books?id=_sj8BAAAQBAJ&dq=radar%20%22false%20echo%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

---

The term *false echo* is used in meteorology radars too along with *anomalous propagation (AP)*.

<sub>http://www.theweatherprediction.com/habyhints/247/</sub>

Comment: +1 for **spurious**. This is the word I've always heard in electronics and instrumentation: A spurious signal, a spurious warning light, a spurious trip.

Answer (score 7):

That is 'clutter'. The word is sometimes used specifically to refer to the nearby wave-peaks which can be picked out by marine radar.

> **clutter**, n.
>
> 2c. **Unwanted images on a radar screen.**
>
> 1945   in Army & Navy Jrnl. (U.S.) 18 Aug. 1534.
>
> 1946   Electronic Engin. 18 267   *Sea clutter, caused by echoes from the tips of waves and broken water.*
>
> 1948   Electronic Engin. 20 336   *The important subject of unwanted echoes (‘clutter’).*
>
> 1967   Electronics 6 Mar. 52/2   *Blind spots caused when the transmitter pulse or clutter obliterates the target return pulse.*

["clutter, n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2014. Web. 21 November 2014.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34898)

Comment: Clutter does not necessarily mean **fake** radar readings as images caused by terrain, trees, weather and other such uninteresting reflectors, as far as they're not wanted, are clutter. There's a tradeoff between clutter and radar sensitivity.

Comment: @PkP, I see what you mean. That's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

**FALSE ALARM**

The technical term for any false detection from a radar system is called a **False Alarm**.

A simple definition for a false alarm is found at [radartutorial.eu](http://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/False%20Alarm%20Rate.en.html):

> A false alarm is “an erroneous radar target detection decision caused by noise or other interfering signals exceeding the detection threshold”.

Target detecting radars make detection decisions using various algorithms, and the threshold mentioned above is the composition of criteria used to determine whether the received signal is actually that of a real target.

There are a lot of factors that can go into such an algorithm, including things like the repeatability of the returned signal (is it present on a majority of the pulses?), on the doppler characteristics (some radars only look for targets that are moving, so signals from non-moving objects are filtered out or rejected) and is it at the expected range or elevation (if the target looks like a ballistic missile coming from a nearby parking lot, there may be a good reason to filter it).

Targets that don't shouldn't pass the filtering algorithm but do are called **false alarms**.

The article I referred to above describes some of the basics for determining what is called the *false alarm rate* for a radar, which is important for determining its expected performance.

Radars have been designed for many years now to disregard non-moving targets like *clutter*, *spurious signals* (including *ghosts* and *sidelobe returns*) and local interference so that they are not "detected" or recognized as targets. Occasionally the radar makes an error in its decision making and that error is called a *false alarm*.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detection_theory#Psychology) provides a description of the *false alarm* in terms of detection theory and hypothesis testing that can be summarized in this picture:

[image]

When the stimulus is not really there, but the decision erroneously says the stimulus is present, this is a *false alarm*. In the mathematical analysis of a decision making process like this, the algorithm takes the form of [hypothesis testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Analogy_.E2.80.93_Courtroom_trial), where this kind of error is called a *Type 1 Error*.

**FALSE TARGET**
False targets are intentionally generated radar signals intended to fake or resemble real radar signal returns with sufficient fidelity that they overcome the radar's decision making algorithms. Faking radar signals is a small part of [Radar Jamming and Deception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_jamming_and_deception#Countermeasures). It is also referred to as *deceptive jamming* or *spoofing*.